# Same code gives different output for each variable

Tags: c

I have written a function that removes leading zeros and white spaces. I am testing it using strlen(). Both should be zero for my input.

Full code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


char *lstrip(const char *a, const char *b)
{
 
  char* a1 = malloc(strlen(a)+1);
  char* b1 = malloc(strlen(b)+1);
  strcpy(b1,b);
  strcpy(a1,a);
  
 for(int i = 0; i < strlen(a); i++){
   if(*(a1+i) == '0' || *(a1+i) == ' '){
     a1++;
     i = -1;
   }
   else{
     break;
   }
 }  
  
 for(int i = 0; i < strlen(b); i++){
   if(*(b1+i) == '0' && *(b1+i) == ' '){
     b1++;
    i = -1;
   }
   else{
     break;
   }
 }
  
  printf("strlen a1 %d \n",strlen(a1));
  printf("strlen b1 %d \n",strlen(b1));

  return " ";
}

int main(){
  lstrip("00000000000000000000000000000","00000000000000000000000000000");
}
```

For some reason the output is

```
strlen a1 0 
strlen b1 29
```

Eventhough the same code is used for a1 and b1

I have tried running the b1 loop first. The output is still the same. What could be the reason for this?

Note: I am using this function for a different purpose than printing it out. Thats why it takes in 2 strings.

Comment: Change `malloc(strlen(a));` to `malloc(strlen(a)+1);` (same for 'b', too)... You've forgotten about the `'\0'` at the end of both strings..

Comment: @Fe2O3 I did that but the output is still the same. I will edit my question to include your change

Comment: `a1[i] == '0'` is much more readable than `*(a1+i) == '0'`

Comment: Also, `strlen()` returns `size_t`, not `int`, so the proper format specifier is `%zu`, not `%d`.  Using the wrong format specifier invokes undefined behavior, so it's possible though not likely that's the cause of your problem.

Comment: Consider this: Is `"0000"` to become `""` or `"0"`? You probably want `"001"` to become `"1"`.

Comment: You can `#include <iso646.h>` (see [C11 7.9](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.9)) and use alternative spellings for `||` and `&&` and a few other operators ... `if ((*(b1+i) == '0') and (*(b1+i) == ' ')) /*...*/;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the below:

```
if(*(b1+i) == '0' && *(b1+i) == ' '){
```

to

```
if(*(b1+i) == '0' || *(b1+i) == ' '){
```

Comment: I completely failed to notice that! That fixes my issue. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Is it right that in the a strip you want to use different logic functions in `a` and `b` strings?

```
if(*(a1+i) == '0' || *(a1+i) == ' '){
```

This says if its `'0'` or `' '` for the a string.

```
if(*(b1+i) == '0' && *(b1+i) == ' '){
```

This says it has to be `'0'` AND `' '` to run.

I assume you want them to be the same?

Answer (score 0):

> What could be the reason for this?

**Save time: [Enable all compiler warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57842756/2410359)**

This is far faster and more productive than posting on SO.

```
warning: logical 'and' of mutually exclusive tests is always false [-Wlogical-op]
  if(*(b1+i) == '0' && *(b1+i) == ' '){
```

(At least 4 more warnings too.)